# How can I find out if the terminal is in the bottom panel or the side panel as a 'when' clause context key in my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Since V1.64 of VSCode there is a new Side Panel which can contain views such as the terminal. I need my extension to perform a different action based on if the terminal is in the 'old' bottom panel or the 'new' side panel. Is there a context key I can use to determine the location of the terminal?

I have tried to use `terminal.defaultViewContainerLocation` and `terminal.defaultViewLocation` but both of these don't seem to work.

There is an Enum called `vscode.TerminalLocation` but it does not have a value for the Side Panel.

The `activeAuxiliary` context key could be useful but I don't know how it works. Sometimes it displays a value with random numbers at the end when the terminal is inside the Side Panel.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The new panel [broke some workflows](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141349). It seems like it's just not fully implemented, yet. Please open a GitHub issue for this in the VS Code repository.

Comment: I made an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142909